VSC Remote SSH: How to save changes to both the remote and local disks?
I use Visual Studio's Remote SSH tool for developing an application that uses a Raspberry Pi.
I would like to save all changes to both the local and remote disk, but I don't see an option for that.
How can I save changes to both my local and remote project folders?

saving to disk and saving in a SCM repository are 2 different kind of operations, put the remote repo as a remote repo for the local repo, and then just pull from the correct remote repo in a terminal on the local disk

@rioV8 You're right, that was poorly worded.  The issue with that is I often forget to scp the changes back to my local disk, which has led to code loss in the past.  If that is the only solution, I would prefer to simply update my local local disk first, then scp the changes to the remote disk.

That being said, this feature was available in the Atom equivalent Remote-SSH extension.
